# Liferay Autologin Hook produces 'Your request failed to complete' in portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I've done a custom Autologin Filter which seems to works well, but when Liferay redirects to the main page (once the user has been authenticated), the login portlet shows an error that I cannot understand.

The error shows "**Your request failed to complete**", but the user has been successfully  logged and if I press F5 or navigate through the page, the error disappear.

My Autologin class implementation is:

```
public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {
    String[] credentials = new String[3];

    String p_id = request.getParameter("p_p_id");
    String userName = null;
    String password = null;
    if (p_id != null) {
        userName = request.getParameter("_" + p_id + "_login");
        password = request.getParameter("_" + p_id + "_password");
        //Custom authentication code required [...]
    }
    if (userName != null) {
        // New Login
        try {

            //We log as Test user...just for TEST
            long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request);
            User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId, "Test");
            long userId = user.getUserId();
            String userPwd = user.getPassword();

            credentials[0] = Long.toString(userId);
            credentials[1] = userPwd;
            credentials[2] = Boolean.FALSE.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AutoLoginException(e);
        }
    return credentials;

    }
    return credentials;
}
```

I've also implemented a Custom Authenticator which always return SUCCESS.

Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

Ivan fontanals

Comment: There are no errors in the log. All seems to be working well. The error only is shown in the returned page...I'm going to upload a screenshot.  Thank you Sharana!